# Strange behavior of compton composite manager with several terminals (i3 wm)

Tags: terminal, transparency, i3-window-manager

I am using `i3` window manager and `compton` composite manager to make some windows transparent. Here is my `compton.conf`

```
menu-opacity = 0.95;
inactive-opacity = 0.7;#this option doesn't work                                                                  
active-opacity = 0.8;
frame-opacity = 0.7;
inactive-opacity-override = true;
alpha-step = 0.06;
inactive-dim = 0.2;
blur-kern = "3x3box";
blur-background-exclude = [ "window_type = 'dock'", "window_type = 'desktop'" ];
fading = true;
fade-in-step = 0.03;
fade-out-step = 0.03;

opacity-rule = [
"99:class_g = 'Firefox'",
"99:class_g = 'Chromium-browser'"
];

backend = "xrender";
mark-wmwin-focused = true;
mark-ovredir-focused = true;
detect-rounded-corners = true;
detect-client-opacity = true;
refresh-rate = 0;
vsync = "none";
dbe = false;
paint-on-overlay = true;
detect-transient = true;
detect-client-leader = true;
invert-color-include = [ ];
glx-copy-from-front = false;
glx-swap-method = "undefined";
```

Everything (so far) works perfectly but there is one problem which I cannot solve. *If two (or more) terminals open in the same workspace the `inactive-opacity` option doesn't work properly*. Unfocused terminals just become opaque (see the picture). What the ideas?
[image]

---

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and use `xterm` as a terminal emulator.